# ./hdfs-fuse: error while loading shared libraries: libfuse.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: linux-kernel

OS Used : CentOS 6.3 X86_64.
./hdfs-fuse: error while loading shared libraries: libfuse.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tried Everything installed every library but not able to resolve this error.

Help me out please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to run 32bit application on 64bit system. It is possible, however, you must install appropriate 32bit libraries. In your case, 32bit version of FUSE library (libfuse.so.2) is needed.